# В чём разница класса и функции?

Tags: php

В чём разница? Т.е. я пишу свои работы используя function. В принципе ничего проблематичного не встречал, но хотел узнать, в чём же будет отличие если я буду писать используя классы? 
Плииз не пинайте на маны, вкратце от себя отпишитесь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Выйди на улицу - все смешалось : люди, машины, дома, деревья... Что это - объекты!!! Человек воспринимает сначала объекты, а потом то, что с этими обьектами происходит, т е функции... Писать программы в стиле ООП - заложено в самом человеке! Поэтому-то, писать надо на объектах. Что касается php - неуверен... Мне, почему-то, не понравилась реализация ООП в php... Если C++/Java/C# - тут однозначно, только ООП!

Answer (score 2):

Для тебя разницы никакой не будет.
Это не троллинг, это факт.

Возможно, со временем прочтешь несколько мануалов, пару книжек, пощупаешь чужой код, попробуешь пару лет писать свой - и начнешь потихоньку понимать.
А может и не начнешь. Программирование сложная наука, не всем по плечу.
В этом, опять же, никакой обиды - голый факт. Не всем же быть нейрохирургами и летчиками-истребителями. Вот и в программировании так же.

Вопрос, повторюсь, звучит как "Ну-ка черканите мне пару фраз, как вырезать саркому аккуратненько. Я чувак опытный, сотни заноз вытащил и даже два раза фурункулы вскрывал".

У меня каждый раз ёкает, когда я иду ко врачу, и я думаю что там сидит такой вот "вы мне отпишитесь тут по-быстрому, мануалов я не люблю".

Comment: как бы, занимаюсь программированием уже несколько лет) И "щупал" чужой код и своего много чего написал, и этим люди пользуются по сей день. (один проект 3 тысячи абонентов, второй около 6 тысяч.)

Comment: Думаю, понимание модет быть связано не только с проектами (количество каких-то там "абонентов" - это информация абсолютно ни о чём вообще), и даже не с их объёмами. Можно написать сотни тысяч строк кода и спокойно обходиться ФП. А во-первых, с разными предметными областями/архитектурами. И во-вторых, с используемыми языками. Например, ко мне понимание начало постепенно приходить только после того, как начал относительно свободно программировать на третьем по счёту, что ли. Может и позже, но не раньше точно.

Comment: @klopp, ФП-то вам чем не угодило. Оно не имеет отношения к программированию на php "без классов".

Comment: Опечатка мозга, поправить не успел :)

Comment: @Ипатьев , не надо перекручивать мой вопрос, он написан однозначно. Я достаточно времени размышлял задавать его или нет.

Answer (score 1):

В программировании на данный момент есть две основные парадигмы. Функциональная и объектно-ориентированная. На первый взгляд, они различаются только подходом к организации функций; на самом деле, каждая из них накладывает свои ограничения и предполагает свой подход практически ко всему (архитектуре, организации кода и т.п.). Например, ООП предполагает выполнение принципа единой ответственности (Single Responsibility) - любой класс занимается только одним делом, посты не умеют сохраняться, консольное приложение ничего не знает об ANSI, в то время как в ФП само понятие компонента крайне разымто. На этом этапе действительно разница будет выглядеть исключительно в организации функционала, но так или иначе в любой парадигме вы начнете спотыкаться при неверной архитектуре, и в тот момент начнете понемногу понимать, какой именно отпечаток налагает тот или иной подход.

Comment: спасибо, прийму к сведению. =)

Comment: Программирование с использованием функций в смысле "подпрограмм"- это структурное программирование. [Функциональное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - это программирование при котором котором процесс вычисления трактуется как вычисление значений функций в математическом понимании последних. Называть кодинг "фунциями без классов" в PHP функциональным программированием, мягко говоря, неверно.